# Does this FreeAndNil(lAux) frees my double field too?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, reference, delphi-7

I'm correcting some (a lot) memory leaks of a project. I have some Delphi experience but is not my main language so I'm extra careful at freeing stuff.
I've already tried it and everything looks fine, but I thought that it would free the Field too (not what I want). Does that happen just with Objects?

```
TMainObject = class(TObject)
public
  FDoubleField : double;
*
*
*
procedure TMainObject.CalculateSomeFieldValue();
var
  lAux : TAuxObject;
begin
  lAux := TAuxObject.Create;
  lAux.RecoverData;

  if **some condition** then 
  begin
    FDoubleField := lAux.DoubleProperty;
  end
  else
  begin
    FDoubleField := lAux.OtherDoubleProperty;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(lAux);
end
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: I do not want to lose FDoubleField because I will use it later, but I need to free lAux.

Comment: `FDoubleField` is only a variable. There is no special memory allocated for it, and therefore nothing to free. There's also no need to use `FreeAndNil` for a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the procedure.

Comment: @KenWhite “*There’s no need to use `FreeAndNil()` for a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the procedure*” - to avoid any confusion: don’t avoid freeing the memory at all, just don’t use `FreeAndNil(lAux)` for that, use `lAux.Free()` instead. There is no need to `nil` out a pointer that will no longer be used.

Comment: Rather than arguing over whether the reference variable is set to nil, the more serious issue is the potential leak because you don't use try/finally.

Comment: The rule is simple. You need to free anything you create. You created an object of type TAuxObject so you need to free it. But you did not create FDoubleField so you need not free it.(in fact you cannot even create FDoubleField because its not an object)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, it clarified some doubts.

Answer (score 3):

The `FDoubleField` field doesn't need to be freed because it will be automatically "freed" as soon it goes out of scope.

**Some tips:**

1. You don't need to use `FreeAndNil(lAux)` in this case, just use `lAux.Free` because there's no need to set a pointer to `nil` which will no longer be used.
2. At the beginning, you can set `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := True` ([documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown)). In this way, you will be notified about any memory leak when the application closes.
3. Use `try-finally` blocks for being sure to always free the object you created

**Modified code using `try-finally` block and `Free`:**

```
procedure TMainObject.CalculateSomeFieldValue();
var
  lAux : TAuxObject;
begin
  lAux := TAuxObject.Create;
  try
    lAux.RecoverData;

    if **some condition** then 
    begin
      FDoubleField := lAux.DoubleProperty;
    end
    else
    begin
      FDoubleField := lAux.OtherDoubleProperty;
    end;
  finally
    lAux.Free;
  end;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give, you don't need to free anything for a variable of type double in a class (Also called a "field").

Field that must be freed are classes or simple pointers of any type that have been allocated.

The normal place to free data in a class is in the `destructor`.

Also pay attention to interfaces. They are generally reference counted and as such MUST NOT be freed. Frequently, interfaces are assigned a value by calling a class constructor and you must really look if the value returned by the class constructor is assigned to a variable of an interface type or to a variable of some object type. Assuming `TAuxObject` also implement the interface `IAuxInterface`, your have the following valid code:

```
var
  AuxObj  : TAuxObject;
  AuxIntf : IAuxInterface;
begin
  AuxIntf := TAuxObject.Create;  // This one must NOT be freed
  AuxObj  := TAuxObject.Create;  // This one must be freed
  try
     ....
  finally
     AuxObj.FRee;
  end;
end;
```

Properly using interfaces is a big subject. There are cases where interfaces are not reference counted.

There are in Delphi libraries a few classes designed to be ancestor for object supporting interface (For example `TInterfacedObject`). This ancestor implement reference counting properly (Methods `QueryInterface`, `_AddRef` and `_Release`). If your object do no derive from a class already implementing reference counting, then if you need  reference counting then you must implement methods `QueryInterface`, `_AddRef` and `_Release`. As soon as they are defined, some compiler magic will call them when it is needed. And by the way freeing the object must actually done by the _Release method implementation.

Things becomes even more complex if the developer make use of `weak` and `unsafe` keywords to mark the interface type variable.

Comment: Interfaces are *not* necessarily reference-counted. For example, in this situation, if TAuxObject inherits from TInterfacedObject, it will be freed properly when the interface variable goes out of scope, but if it inherits from TComponent, it will leak.

Comment: @KenBourassa If an object implement an interface and don't inherit from TInterfacedObject, it has to implement the IInterface methods QueryInterface, _AddRef and _Release. Not doing it is an error although the compiler is kind enough to accept your problem.

Comment: First, it's not true to say the compiler will compile a class supporting an interface without implementing QueryInterface, _AddRef and _Release.  TComponent DOES implement them, but does not implement reference counting. So your code above WILL leak if TAuxObj is inherited from TComponent and it is by design. So... I'm not sure what your point is here.

Comment: @KenBourassa If you inherit from TComponent, you can implement QueryInterface, _AddRef and _Release whenever you need reference counting. I have not shown the code for TAuxObject so you can't say it will leak memory! Be convinced that if properly implemented, even if deriving from TComponent, it will NOT leak memory. Since it is not really on topic here, please ask a new question like "How to write an TComponent derived class with interface reference counting". I will then publish the code as an answer. But I'm sure you could write it yourself...

Comment: "Since it is not really on topic here". I'm sorry, but it IS on topic here.  You seem to claim that interface are inherently reference counted and "can never leak" and that any interface that isn't reference-counted is "wrong", which is definitely not the case. Not making the distinction in your answer is a disservice to the OP. And don't worry, I don't need to ask a question on the subject, I understand the suject very well.